# Force IK rig to bend knee "Wrong" way?

Tags: inverse-kinematics

[image]

I've designed this mech's legs so they can fold up when crouched but that left the knee pivot behind the top one so my IK rig bends my leg the wrong way. Can I have my knee behind the "pelvis" and force the knee to bend forward still?

Thank you!

Comment: Even in a real world robot, pulling up the foot would lead to the "incorrect" way. You have to tell him if you want walk or fold. I think the better way is to use IK for walking (where it's useful) and FK for folding (which is simple), so it would be better to choose a forward bending as rest pose.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
It turns out I was overthinking this problem. I simply had to bend the knees before I rig it.

Comment: Then it doesn't fold-- same problem as before, just in reverse.  You need to control the direction of the bend by bending the calf in pose mode.